# How to show date picker on the onclick of text field instead of keyboard in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Wish to show date picker when clicking on the `TextFormField` instead of the keyboard. I have tried using `GestureDetector` but not working as I expected.

```
DateTime _date = new DateTime.now();
TimeOfDay _time = new TimeOfDay.now();

Future<Null> _selectedDate(BuildContext context) async {
  final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _date,
      firstDate: new DateTime(2016),
      lastDate: new DateTime(2019));

  if (picked != null && picked != _date) {
    print("Date selected ${_date.toString()}");
    setState(() {
      _date = picked;
    });
  }
}
 ......
new GestureDetector(

       onTap: (){
         _selectedTime(context);
             },
            child:
             new TextFormField(
              initialValue: convertToDate(_date),
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                  hintText: 'Enter your date of event',
                  labelText: 'Date',
                ),
                keyboardType: null,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Look at this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51798669/3123267 .If this is what you meant and you didn't got the idea, tell me to put the answer with example.

Answer (score 22):

You can wrap your `TextFormField` with an `AbsorbPointer` (see [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html)). It will "absorb" the incoming standard behavior on the child so clicking the TextFormField would do nothing. If you now wrap the `AbsorbPointer`using a `GestureDetector` you can use the `onTap()` method to call your showDatePicker method.

```
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
TextEditingController _date = new TextEditingController();

Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
  final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1901, 1),
      lastDate: DateTime(2100));
  if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
    setState(() {
      selectedDate = picked;
      _date.value = TextEditingValue(text: picked.toString());
    });
}

// inside Widget build
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
  child: AbsorbPointer(
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: _date,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Date of Birth',
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.dialpad,
          color: _icon,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 20):

You can wrap your `TextField` with `AbsorbPointer` , so your widget tree would look something like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap:()=>showDialog(),
  child:AbsorbPointer(
    child: MyTextField(),
  )
)
```

Comment: and what should i do if i want to use both textField for remove date and pick a date from datepicker?

Answer (score 7):

The other answers here have many widgets to get the job done. But this can simply done by using **`TextFormField`** only. Just **set the widget to read only** (so that it doesn't take inputs) and **then define an onTap**. The controller attached to it will take the value from the date picker.

First create a `TextFormField` widget like this:

```dart
TextFormField(
  readOnly: true, //this is important
  onTap: _selectDate,  //the method for opening data picker
  controller: _textcontroller,  //the controller
),
```

Now write the `_selectDate` function:

```dart
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();

_selectDate() async {
  final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: dateTime,
      initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101));
  if (picked != null) {
    dateTime = picked;
    //assign the chosen date to the controller
    _textController.text = DateFormat.yMd().format(dateTime);
  }
}
```

Personally I think this is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
      child: AbsorbPointer(
        child: TextField(
          controller: textController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            labelText: widget.hintText,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 16),
            // pass the hint text parameter here
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 16),
            suffixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.calendar_today),
          ),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
    );


Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1901, 1),
        lastDate: DateTime(2100));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
        String convertedDateTime = "${picked.year.toString()}-${picked.month.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}-${picked.day.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}";
       // widget.textController.value = TextEditingValue(text: picked.toString());
        widget.textController.value = TextEditingValue(text: convertedDateTime);;
      });
  }
```

Result

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```dart
TextField(
  controller: TextEditingController()
    ..text = reservationProvider.date,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      suffixIcon: ImageIcon(
    AssetImage('images/calendar_today.png'),
    color: Colors.black,
  )),
  readOnly: true,
  onTap: () async {
    final date = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        firstDate: DateTime(1960),
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        lastDate: DateTime(2100));
    if (date != null) {
      print(date);
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: you should at least put some intro text before showing the code, so that people know what you provide. Then you should format the code properly. Nobody likes to read code like a story in a book.